# Prove set is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

This particular problem is confusing me a bit. Heres the problem.

Let $X$ be a non empty set, and $B$ a subset of $X$. Show that the system

$$E := \{A \subseteq X : B \subseteq A \; \text{or} \; B  \subseteq A^c\}$$

is a $\sigma$-algebra (on $X$).

However to me this looks just like the power set, as no matter what $B$ is then $A \subseteq X$ can be any set in $X$, and still satisfy the predicate. In that case it is obviously a $\sigma$-algebra, but I think I must have made a mistake, so I'm wondering  what I might have missed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have missed:

Let $X= \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$

$B=\{1,2\}$.

Let $A = \{ 1\}$, then $A^C = \{2,3,4\}$.

We have $B \not\subseteq A$ and $B \not\subseteq A^C$, hence we can see that $A$ cannot just be any subset of $X$.

You have to verify the property that it indeed satisfies the property of a sigma algebra. That is it contains the universal set, closure under complement and closure under countable union.